# How to read large file in chunks using REST api

Tags: development, rest, csom, large-file

I want to download the large files(more than 10MB) in chunks. I didn't find any method in CSOM. How can I get the large file in chunks?

Please suggest the solution.
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems not supported to use chunk download file using REST API f
Please check the below link once.

MSDN Link: [Download large files using REST](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/03e55d41-1daf-46a5-b61d-2d80139123f4/download-large-files-using-rest?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Stack Exchange link : [download partial by using GetFileById sharepoint REST-API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/188419/download-partial-by-using-getfilebyid-sharepoint-rest-api)

If you want to download files using CSOM  please check the below links

[Download Large Files from SharePoint Online](https://piyushksingh.com/2016/08/15/download-large-files-from-sharepoint-online/)

Stack Exchange LInk: [Download Large Files from SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184789/download-large-files-from-sharepoint-online)

Comment: Tried with the above example  but getting response as
<html><head><title>vermeer RPC packet</title></head>
<body>
<p>method=get document:15.0.0.4455
<p>status=
<ul>
<li>status=589830
<li>osstatus=0
<li>msg=There is no file with URL 'https://mysp.sharepoint.com/sites/communicationsite1/Doc1.docx' in this Web.
<li>osmsg=
</ul>
</body>
</html>